# cfengine 3.4 - cygwin build instructions

Tags: cfengine

I would like to build cfengine 3.4 on cygwin.

It appears that this should be possible - here is patch to enable the build: [link](https://github.com/cfengine/core/pull/179).

Are there any step by step build instructions for compiling cfengine 3.4 on cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install cygwin (I setup 1.7.17) with:

- make
- gcc
- flex
- bison
- openssl-devel
- libpcre-devel

Download qdbm from [here](http://fallabs.com/qdbm/qdbm-1.8.78.tar.gz), then:

```
tar xvzf qdbm-1.8.78.tar.gz
cd qdbm-1.8.78
./configure
make
install
cp /usr/local/lib/libqdbm.* /usr/lib
```

Download cfengine from [here](http://cfengine.com/source-code/download?file=cfengine-3.4.3.tar.gz), then:

```
tar xvzf cfengine-3.4.3.tar.gz
cd cfengine-3.4.3
./configure --with-qdbm
make
make install
```

Now I just need to figure out how to use cfengine!